# jquery animate variable from bound function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/1/

I'm using a twitter script which i'm binding a function to get the dynamic height of div#tweet, once the tweet has loaded.

But I then need to pass that variable into a .animate script after - this is what I got so far.

```
    $("#tweet").tweet({
        count: 1,
        username: ["motocomdigital"],
        loading_text: "searching twitter...",
        intro_text: null,
        outro_text: null
    }).bind("loaded", function(){

        // this binded function is getting the height of tweet div once loaded...
        var tweetHeight = $("#tweet").height();

    });
```

I then need to pass the variable **tweetHeight** into an animation script i'm running below. Simple I thought but I think I'm coding it slightly wrong.

```
    $latestTweet.hover(function() {
        // see variable in this is first alternation
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top: "-" + tweetHeight + "px", width: "512px", 
    }, function() {
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top: "-1px", width: "334px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);
    });
```

Lets say the div#tweet height (once the twitter content is loaded) is 200px, I need the result of this variable to be...

```
$latestTweet.stop().animate({ top: "-200px", width: "512px",
```

Can anyone help me understand how write this correctly - I've even tried putting my animate scripts inside the binded function, but still its not passing the variable.

**MAJOR UPDATE**

Ive just figured out why its giving the wrong height of the #tweet div! Its because my #tweet div has top and bottom padding, and the **.height** is not including those dimensions when creating the **tweetHeight** variable, see [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/1/)

Does anyone know how I can add fixed pixel dimensions to my **tweetHeight** variable? For example an extra 50px?

The reason also why I'm binding it to the twitter javascript is because the height of the #tweet div is dynamic in height, hence the animation from the top position, always need the final height of the #tweet div to position it perfect. See for simplified demo [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to create a variable outside the function:

```
var tweetHeight = 200; // a default height
// here come's the $.tweet() code, and you should only assign the new value to the "tweetHeight" variable

//$latestTweet.stop().animate({ top: -tweetHeight ...
```

**UPDATE to "MAJOR UPDATE" above**

You can manipulate this extra pixels if you set the variable value using a function:

```
var tweetHeight = 200;
function setTweetHeight(h) {
    tweetHeight = h + 50;
}
```

Now use the function to assign the new value:

```
setTweetHeight( $('#tweet').height() ); // example
```

Comment: ahh yeh but the tweet is dynamic, and i've literall just figure out my problem when doing the jsfiddle - the height it's retrieving of the div is not including my padding - do you now how i can add my top and bottom padding dimensions on my tweetHeight variable? Thanks [http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/)